# Convert text file to multi-dimensional array vertically (not line by line)

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the following text file that I fetched in a variable called `myText`:

```
file.txt:
1,5,9
2,6,0
3,7,0
4,8,0

myText = // content of file.txt
```

I want to get a two dimensional array that looks like this from `myText` by grouping the elements in each column:

```
my2DArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all lines have the same number of elements, you can first construct a two-dimensional array of numbers from the text and then use `Array.from` to get the elements in each column.

```js
let myText = `1,5,9
2,6,0
3,7,0
4,8,0`;
const parts = myText.split('\n').map(x => x.split(',').map(Number));
const res = Array.from({length: parts[0].length}, 
   (_,i)=>Array.from({length: parts.length}, (_,j)=>parts[j][i]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const myText = `1,5,9
2,6,0
3,7,0
4,8,0`;

const my2DArray = myText
                   .split('\n')
                   .map(row => row.split(',').map(Number)) // Reversed 2D Array
                   .reduce((acc, row) => {
                     if (acc.length) {
                       return acc.map((r, i) => r.concat(row[i]));
                     }
                     return row.map(v => [v]);
                   }, []); // Rotated matrix
                 
console.log(my2DArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more optimized version (a bit faster) with fewer iterations.

```js
const myText = 
`1,5,9   
2,6,0
3,7,0
4,8,0`;

const rows = myText.split('\n');
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const row = rows[i].split(',');
    for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        if (result[j] === undefined) {
            result[j] = [parseInt(row[j])]
        } else {
            result[j].push(parseInt(row[j]))
        }
    }
}
console.log(result)
```